# Automatically remove empty string

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-model

My template

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <p class="required">4. How did you hear about our distribution?</p>
   <p id="skip">Check all that apply</p>
   <b-form-checkbox v-for="item in choices" :key="item" :value="item" v-model="socialMedia" required> {{ item }} </b-form-checkbox>
   <b-form-checkbox v-on:click="onclick"> Other: </b-form-checkbox>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" :disabled='isDisabled' v-model="other">
      <button name="btn" v-show="!isDisabled" @click="addType" required>+</button>
   <span class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ socialMedia }}</strong></span>
   <br>
   <span class="mt-3">Additional check: <strong>{{ other }}</strong> <br><label id="small">Do NOT forget to click PLUS button for optional</label></span>
</div>
```

My Vue Instance:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
      choices: ['Facebook', 'Instagram', 'Twitter', 'Word of Mouth', 'KMAZ 102.5fm'],
      isDisabled: true,
      other: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onclick() {
      this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled
      if (this.selected.length) {
        this.selected = this.selected.filter(s => s !== this.other)
      }
      this.other = ''
    },
    addType() {
      this.socialMedia.push(this.other)
    }
  }
}
```

This Vue project will create a checkbox list that allows users to add multiple values and optional. For example, Other box is checked and no values are entered, then click + button, this will add an empty string to the array.

[image]

I was trying to do like below, but it did not work:

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <p class="required">4. How did you hear about our distribution?</p>
   <p id="skip">Check all that apply</p>
   <b-form-checkbox v-for="item in choices" :key="item" :value="item" v-model="socialMedia" @change="DetectedEmptyString()"required> {{ item }} </b-form-checkbox>
   <b-form-checkbox v-on:click="onclick"> Other: </b-form-checkbox>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" :disabled='isDisabled' v-model="other">
      <button name="btn" v-show="!isDisabled" @click="addType" required>+</button>
   <span class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ socialMedia }}</strong></span>
   <br>
   <span class="mt-3">Additional check: <strong>{{ other }}</strong> <br><label id="small">Do NOT forget to click PLUS button for optional</label></span>
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
      choices: ['Facebook', 'Instagram', 'Twitter', 'Word of Mouth', 'KMAZ 102.5fm'],
      isDisabled: true,
      other: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onclick() {
      this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled
      if (this.selected.length) {
        this.selected = this.selected.filter(s => s !== this.other)
      }
      this.other = ''
    },
    addType() {
      this.socialMedia.push(this.other)
    },
    DetectedEmptyString() {
      return this.socialMedia.filter(x => x !== "")
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**: No matter how many times I click + button, the empty string is automatically removed.

Comment: Share your  *https://jsfiddle.net/* or *https://stackblitz.com/*  link

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-7er6bm?file=src/App.vue

Comment: What is `this.socialMedia`? Did you mean `this.selected`?

Comment: hey cristian here is update one *https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-9a6yg9?file=src/components/Distribution.vue*